# AJAX/JS/PHP/MYSQL - Conflit between an onclick and an onchange when running 2 different AJAX queries

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, function

I'm building a website for a veterinary office where people can register their animals and edit their history.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have 2 different functions, both working with AJAX so I can dynamically update the history of a specific selected animal.

The onchange function is made to get the history of an animal owned by a client and put it as the value of a textarea.

The onclick function is made to update that history once you hit the submit button.

Thing is, once I used the onclick function, the onchange doesn't work, and i'd like to be able to set histories of various animals whithout reloading.

Here is the code of the 2 functions, the Models, and the views (onchange function is in the views, I'll make a seperate file for it once everything will     be smooth)
Thanks for the help :D

Views with getHistory():

```
<div id="txtHint"></div>
<select class="form-control space-bottom" onchange="getHistory()" id="animal" style="width:40%;display:block;margin-auto;margin-top:80px;margin-left:300px"name="target" required>
<?php 
         foreach($patients_rows as $key0 => $value0){
            unset($value0['history']);
            $name = implode(' ',$value0);
            foreach($value0 as $key =>$value){
                    if($key == 'pet_name'){
                        echo '<option " value="'.$value.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                        echo $value;
                    }
            }
        }
?>
</select><div class ="container">
<center style="color:#decba4">
    Ajouter/modifier un historique :<br> <textarea rows="8" cols="50" id="history" name="history" /></textarea><br>
    <input type="hidden" id="owner" name="owner" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['ID'];?>"/>
    <input class = "button " style="margin-left:3%;background:#333333;color:#decba4;border:none" type="button" 
    onclick ='updateHistory(this.value)'name="msg_send" value="Envoyer"></center>
</div>

</body>
<script>
function getHistory(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
     try {
         ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (e) {
         try {
             ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e) {
             try{
                 ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch (e){
                 alert("Your browser broke!");
                 return false;
             }
         }
     }
    /** Crée la connexion et récupère la réponse */

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
          var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('history');
          ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
       }
    }

 /** Valeurs à passer en arguments */
    var a = document.getElementById('animal').value;
    var o = document.getElementById('owner').value;

    var queryString = "?d=" + a ;
    queryString += "&o=" + o;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET","../tests/Models/get_history.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(); 
 }
</script>
</html>
```

updateHistory() js file :

```
function updateHistory(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
     try {
         ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }catch (e) {
         try {
             ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e) {
             try{
                 ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch (e){
                 alert("Your browser broke!");
                 return false;
             }
         }
     }
    /** Crée la connexion et récupère la réponse */

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
          var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('txtHint');
          ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
       }
    }

 /** Valeurs à passer en arguments */
    var a = document.getElementById('animal').value;
    var o = document.getElementById('owner').value;
    var h = document.getElementById('history').value;

    var queryString = "?d=" + a ;
    queryString += "&o=" + o + "&h=" + h;
    ajaxRequest.open("POST","../tests/Models/update_history.php" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(); 
 }
```

getHistory Model:

```
<?php
    include('./db_connect.php');
    $a = $_GET['d'];
    $o = $_GET['o'];

    $query =
    "SELECT history
    FROM patients
    WHERE pet_name = :pet_id
    AND owner_ID = :owner_id";

    $query_params = array(":pet_id" => $a,
                         ":owner_id" => $o);
                         try {
                            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
                            $successmsg = $stmt ->fetchAll();
                            echo $successmsg[0]['history'];
                        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
                        }
    unset($a,$o,$db);
?>
```

update_history model :

```
<?php
    include('./db_connect.php');
    var_dump($_GET);
    $a = $_GET['d'];
    $o = $_GET['o'];
    $h = $_GET['h'];

    $query =
    "UPDATE patients
    SET history = :history
    WHERE pet_name = :pet_id
    AND owner_id = :owner_id";

    $query_params = array(":history" => $h,
                         ":pet_id" => $a,
                         ":owner_id" => $o);
                         try {
                            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
                            $successmsg = "Message envoyé";
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show'style='background:#decba4;text-align:center;margin-left:390px;max-height:80px;font-size:13px;width:180px;color:#FFFFFF;border:0.5px solid #decba4'>
                        ".$successmsg."<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
                        <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                      </button></div>";
                        }catch(PDOException $ex){
                            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
                        }
?>
```

Comment: Post your code in the question. Paste it, select it, then click the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: don't really understand your code but here is a suggestion according to your description remove the onchange function and set it to  window.onload = function(){ i_was_an_onload_fun(); } then also set it to run if the onclick function  updates successfully by including it in the onclick function.

Comment: Done. I don't want it to work this way @BobbyAxe. The aim is to select the pet which you want to retrieve the history, get it from the DB, put it as the value of the medical history of the patient in the textarea so it can be edited and then updated with the onclick.

Comment: to put simply you are to make Three requests (1) select pet (2) update pet (3)show updated pet status all done with out refreshing the page?

Comment: Functions work great separately, I can use one however I want. Only deal here is that I can't get History anymore once I updated one

Comment: Select pet retrieves Pet_name. it's in the controllers (no Ajax there) and put all your pets in a Select(html). But when I change the pet with the select (getHistory/onchange) to any other one, I get the history from DB and put it as the value of the textarea to edit it easily. Once you're done typing and you click, you update with the updateHistory()/onclick. And my only trouble is that I can't use getHistory anymore once I used updateHistory, it won't update the value of my textarea